# How can I apply the same format for first row of a table on every page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

My code (c#, Visual Studio 2017) creates a table in a MS-word, which continues over several pages. I would like to keep the first row, with it's specific content and formatting (a header line actually), at the beginning of every page.

I can't predict how many rows will be on every page. How can I guide the C# code to do that?

Code that creates the Table:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
Table genTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, num_of_people + 1, max_gen + 1, ref missing, ref missing);
                genTable.Borders.Enable = 1;
```

Comment: MS Word tables have an option to "repeat header rows". You designate one or more header rows at the top of the table and they will be repeated on every page. No need to work out how many rows are on each page: Word does it for you.

Comment: @Richard : Correct, but how do I set it from C# within VS2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer for 1) setting a row as the Header row so that it repeats on following pages and 2) enforcing the styling for a Header row:

```
       foreach (Table item in document.Tables)
        {
            item.Rows[1].HeadingFormat = -1;
            item.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = true;
        }
```